# Following touch / using gesture recognizer translation on custom interactive transitioning

Tags: objective-c, ios7, custom-transition

I created a custom transition for navigation controller where as the user pans up, the next controller's view revealed below as the current controller's view moves in upward  direction. I want that view to move by following the touch (as if it is glued to finger at the touch point), but i dont know how to pass that translation from pan gesture recognizer to the object that implements UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning. Well, I do but i cannot access it from inside the [UIView animateWithDuration ... ] block (It seems that block is executed once, I thought it would be executed as percentage of completion changes). How can I accomplish this?

To ask the question in a different way, if you use the Photos app in ios7, when you are looking at a photo, touch with two fingers and pinch /move and you will see that it is following the finger (movements). Any example code for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create a separate animation controller as a subclass of `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` to go along with your custom transition animation. This is the class that will calculate the percentage of how complete your animation is. There's too much to explain in a single SO answer, but have a look at the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition_class/Reference/Reference.html/). You can also refer to one of my implementations of a custom transition animation with interactive abilities [here](https://github.com/chetem/CHFlingToDismissAnimation) to see it in action.

Comment: UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition class has nothing to pass the gesture translation info. That class is helpful when you have a predefined animation with predefined path. I am trying to make a transition whose path depends on the touch location of the user.

Comment: the `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` has a method `interactionControllerForDismissal:` where you pass in your custom `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` controller. This is what allows you to animate your transition using a gesture to calculate the percentage of completion. matt also provided useful code samples to see how it is done.

Comment: Ok, I will look further into it. Also, your second link seems like what I need (need to download and check it out). I will get back

Answer (score 1):

Croberth's answer is correct. You actually have two choices.

- If you want to keep your custom animation, then use a UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition and keep updating it as the gesture proceeds, as in this example of mine:

  https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p296customAnimation2/ch19p620customAnimation1/AppDelegate.m
- However, I prefer to split the controller up into two separate cases; if we are interactive (using a gesture), then I just keep updating the view positions *myself*, manually, as the gesture proceeds, including completing or reversing it at the end, as this in this code:

  https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p300customAnimation3/ch19p620customAnimation1/AppDelegate.m

Comment: For item #1, see explanations above for croberth; For item #2, thanks :) it gives me idea about how to proceed. I will come back to accept if it solves my problem.

Comment: croberth's second link solved my problem. Your second link would solve it as well but I had to accept his answer because it solves my problem and he was the first to answer. Thanks a lot for your answer. I voted it up as well.

Comment: @Nihat Yup, makes sense. I'm glad to have my links in your answer, as they may help someone else.